# Android get Text from EditText in a GridView

Tags: android, string, gridview, textview, android-edittext

I have a GridView that displays several dozen rows worth of a custom layout, each of which consists of an EditText and a TextView object.

If I understand correctly, I should extend the BaseAdapter class to accomplish that. If so, how can I get access to a specific EditText object?

Also, will recycling of views cause me to lose the text that the user has entered if one of the EditText views is no longer visible?

Is there a simpler means to accomplish what I am describing here (perhaps something other than GridView) ?

Comment: have you find solution for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you extend `BaseAdapter` one of the methods you have to override is `getView(...)`. In this method, you create the view that needs to be shown. If you want to persist text that is entered in the `EditText`, what you need to do is set a a `TextWatcher` on the EditText, passing in the position of the EditText (parameter in `getView(...)`), and whenever the text is changed, save the text in an array of sorts. Then, whenever that position comes back through the `getView(...)` method, grab the text from the array and populate the `EditText`.

Comment: Sounds doable, but complicated. Would it be a lot simpler to just use a TableLayout for this (the number of rows shouldn't exceed 100) ?

Comment: If all of your cells are identical in the sense that they each have an EditText and a TextView, then it would not be simpler to use a TableLayout. The power of using an adapter lies in the fact that positions that are off the screen are not stored in memory, giving you a small memory footprint. Whenever you scroll, views going off screen are reused to make the views coming onto the screen.

Comment: I see that when I use a TextWatcher, there are three methods that I am forced to override. In order to update my String array with the updated text, I must know which EditText object that new text belongs to (which I use to get the proper index in my String array). Does the Editable object "know" which one it is?

Comment: That's why I was saying pass the position in when making a custom `TextWatcher` class. Do keep in mind also that you "add" TextWatchers, so you can have multiple ones assigned to a single EditText. Keep that in mind so you don't add more TextWatchers when revisiting a view.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an underlying data structure ( say a List ) which should hold the data for each  element of the Grid.

TextView and EditText should be populated from this List.